# The AlertDialog does not appear on the screen when the application is killed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

Warns the user when wifi is turned on; I want to show a popup on the screen. I tried to do it with broadcast and service. However, it does not work after the application is killed.

My Service Code :

```
public class AlertService extends Service {

private static Context context;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertService.this).create();
    alertDialog.setMessage("Nek Test");
    alertDialog.setTitle("Reminder");
    alertDialog.setButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
    }else{
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    }
    new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }.start();
    return flags;
}
```

MainActivity :

```
private BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

        switch (wifiStateExtra){
            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                this.context = context;
                startService(new Intent(context, AlertService.class));
            break;
            case  WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: your broadcast receiver is registered in main activity and there is no instance of main activity running after you kill your application. consider showing a Notification instead.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot start activity from the background in case app has been killed on recent Android devices.

I can recommend you to do next things:
1. check if your service continue running after killing the app. If it doesn't - you need to make it independent from app lifecycle.
2. you could show a toast \ full screen intent to notify a user

Comment: How can I check the service after the application is killed?

Comment: you could override `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods with adding log  printings to see when when are called in logcat